# config.MapODataServiceRoute error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am currently following this guide -> [Link to asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

As the guide says I added all the necessary packages via the nuget console and added the necessary usings to the WebApIConfig file. . But when I added the endpoint register method VS gave me an error.

The method I added:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code:
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
```

The Error VS gave me:

```
Error   1   'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'MapODataServiceRoute' and no extension method 'MapODataServiceRoute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\rvcamp\Desktop\odataTest\odataTest\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs   29  20  odataTest
```

I checked the comments of the guide but this error is not mentioned, also I can not resolve the error either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind it is solved now. I reinstalled the odata nugget and rebuild the project.

Comment: I will never understand why microsoft omits using namespaces in their sample code. It slows down every guide by 2x.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just had this problem. Very frustrating.

I resolved it by adding this in the references at the top of the code page

```
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
```

Right clicking the method did not bring up the resolve menu item either.

Reinstalling everything did no resolve anything for me.

Comment: Yes I did this as well, still find it very odd.

Comment: Oh definitely, one would think if you right-click on 'MapODataServiceRoute' method in code it would automatically resolve the issue by importing the namespace. But no :(

Comment: Correct namespace for OData v4 is `using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;`

Comment: For `Microsoft.AspNet.OData 7.0.0` see @Amir answer below.  Very helpful for the present time.

Answer (score 14):

*MapODataServiceRoute is available in Routes Collection, hence below code will do*

```
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
"odata",
 null, 
GetEdmModel(), 
new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

Comment: This depends: For OData3 you call `config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute` and for OData4 you use `config.MapODataServiceRoute` (and for OData1-2 you use `config.Routes.MapODataRoute`).

Answer (score 12):

**FOR OData V3**

1. Install Microsoft.AspNet.**WebApi**.OData
2. Add `using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;` and `using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;`
3. use like `config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(...)`

**FOR OData V4**

1. Install Microsoft.AspNet.OData
2. Add `using System.Web.OData.Builder;` and `using System.Web.OData.Extensions;`
3. use like `config.MapODataServiceRoute(...)`

*Dont get stuck on WebApi word, they are both for web api.*

Answer (score 6):

If you have upgraded to `Microsoft.AspNet.OData 7.0.0` then the namespace you are looking for is:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;
```

Comment: This is like playing the game: "Find the Namespace"
Thank you for pointing me to this namespace.  Is there any documentation that I am overlooking that makes this clear?

Comment: I used ILSPY since I couldn't find anything decent when I looked for it..

Answer (score 4):

`MapODataServiceRoute` is extension method. So to use it a reference to its namespace is required. For me it was fixed by referencing:

```
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;
```

Comment: And I'm guessing because it's an extension method, the right-click resolve reference doesn't know how to give that suggestion?

Comment: *System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions* worked for me where *System.Web.OData.Extensions* did not. Was the namespace switched between versions?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by opening the package manager console, setting the default project to the project that gave the error message, and then:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
```