# Microsoft ODataController response with @odata.context

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using these packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I inserted an ODataController using this technique:

1. Right-click on Controller folder,  "Add Controller"
2. Choose from "Add Scaffold" list the "Web API 2 ODataController with actions, using
   Entity Framework"
3. Choose the appropriate Model and context for this
   ODataController
4. Modify WebApiConfig.cs according to the inserted
   template

When I hit my controller, the result does not include the `@odata.context` property, which throws off the [angular-odataresources library I'm using](https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources/blob/8745ec831d8b627e52be1e37c86ab867af673f62/src/odataresources.js#L364)

The response only includes these two properties:
`{odata.metadata: "...", value: [...]}`

How can I make the ODataController  respond with @odata.context property?

I tried using this, but no change in response:
`$format=application/json;`**`odata.metadata=full`**

**Update**

I just found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn260745.aspx)
Specifically:

> The name of the odata.context annotation is "odata.metadata" and is
>   written without the leading "@"

Does this mean I cannot make ODataController return `@odata.context`?

As a workaround I can always change the Javascript which is thrown off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData supports OData versions 1-3, but the `@odata.context` annotation is specific to version 4. Also, the JSON payload formats are significantly different between versions 3 and 4.

Since you own the service code, your best best is to upgrade the OData implementation to v4. It looks like that's what ODataAngularResources is expecting anyway. Uninstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client and install [Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27535441/1175496 and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0/ were helpful in following your advice.