# config.MapODataServiceRoute and config.MapODataServiceRoute Error

Tags: c#

I am currently following the instructions
at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

I am on step "Configure the OData endpoint". I encountered erroneous lines when I added the new code to the endpoint register method.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code:
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

I have tried all instructions (at [config.MapODataServiceRoute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224702/config-mapodataserviceroute-error)) to fix this. Using the suggestions on this site, I found many
different ways to eliminate the line errors and get a successful build.

However, no matter which solution I use to get a successful build, when I run the service, I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12:         protected void Application_Start()
> Line 13:         {
> Line 14:             GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
> Line 15:         }
>
> Source File: C:\Users<username>\source\repos\ProductService\ProductService\Global.asax.cs    Line: 14
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
> Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatters.CreateApplicationJson() +0
> Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create() +28
> Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataFormattingAttribute.CreateODataFormatters() +5
> Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataFormattingAttribute.Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor) +280
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type) +154
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type) +54
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType) +105
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache() +400
> System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +429 System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +158
> System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +79 System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping() +16 System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider) +48 System.Web.Http.Routing.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__1() +57 System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer) +61
> System.Web.Http.Routing.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(HttpConfiguration config) +91
> System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() +23
> System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1 configurationCallback) +43
> ProductService.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users<username>\source\repos\ProductService\ProductService\Global.asax.cs:14
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +475
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +220
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +303
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core, Version=7.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +659
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4331.0

Answer (score 1):

In the process of upgrading a project from .NET 3 to .NET 6, I ran into the same error.  First issue I ran into was a value cannot be null exception on EnableDependencyInjection line below.

```
app.UseEndpoints(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.MapControllers();
    routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter();
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
});
```

I resolved that by upgrading the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData NuGet package from version 7.5.6 to 7.5.15 based on this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/796).  That got rid of the null exception but caused a new exception.

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Edm,
> Version=7.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> The system cannot find the file specified."

When I downgraded Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData to version 7.5.12 as specified in the GitHub issue, it resolved the error.  Not sure why going with the last version 7 release introduced a new error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it just by updating OData dependent packages through the Nugget package manager window.

**1. Open Package manager**

[image]

**2. Update these packages**

[image]

**3. Rebuild your application**